# shell script to capture stdout and stderr to a file and run process in background

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

I have a shell script in /etc/init.d that launches a python script, here's that line:

```
/pathto/python /pathto/file.py >>/pathto/stdout_stderr.log 2>&1 &
```

The plan is to capture stdout and stderr to a file, and to run the process in the background

I'm seeing information from python subprocesses in the log (from aplay for example) , but no output from python print

The plan is to keep the python simple and reusable, but I'm more willing to change my approach  in the shell script...

Comment: Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after a `print`.